# rotate a plane around a diagonal

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

I would like to rotate a plane, not around a single (X or Y) axis, but around the diagonal (45 degrees between X and Y). How do I calculate the Rx and Ry given the Rdiagonal?

(Rdiagonal is the amount of rotation I would like to achieve around the diagonal axis).

To clarify: just take a yellow PostIt and draw cross on it (a horizonal and a vertical line). These are the X and Y axes. Rotating around these axes is easy (assuming you can just specify Rx and Ry). But I would like to rotate around the diagonal axis. What are the Rx and Ry in that case?

I think it's something like Rx = Rdiagonal / sqrt(2). But I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmmm, I understand how to rotate a plane around a point in 2D.  I understand how to rotate a plane around a line in 3D.  But I suspect that you do not mean the latter operation.  Could you clarify ?

Answer (score 0):

Your plane will most certainly given by some points (depending on the dimensionality). You can then use a rotation matrix to transform these points: new = R * old. Afterwards, construct your plane from these points.

To get the right rotation matrix, see [the entry at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_given_an_axis_and_an_angle).

Comment: -1 for misleading link.  And I don't think this is a good MathOverflow question.  Too easy.

Comment: Woah, I intended to put a wikipedia link there.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably more of a mathoverflow question, but I found some information [here](http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm#Rotation%20about%20an%20Arbitrary%20Axis) about rotation around an arbitrary axis. It provides the derivation for the translation and rotation matrices.

Comment: MathOverflow would probably consider this question too easy and would close it.

Comment: Indeed, MathOverflow is only for "research level math questions" :(

Comment: Your link is dead.